# how can I save and redirect this code?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public with sharing class RentedBike {
    public cust_Ride__c custRide {get;set;}  
    public map<string,Object> inputMap {get;set;}
    public RentedBike() {
        custRide = new cust_Ride__c();
    }

    
    
    public void Savevalue() {
        Map<string,Object> inputMap =new Map<string,Object>();
        inputMap.put('customer__c',custRide.customer__c);
        inputMap.put('Starting_KM__c',custRide.Starting_KM__c);
        inputMap.put('Ending_KM__c',custRide.Ending_KM__c);
        inputMap.put('Ride_Starting_Date__c',custRide.Ride_Starting_Date__c);
        inputMap.put('Ride_Ending_Date__c',custRide.Ride_Ending_Date__c);
        inputMap.put('Active_Price__c',80);
        inputMap.put('Previous_Price__c',75);
        inputMap.put('Current_Price__c',84);
        system.debug(inputMap);
        next(inputMap);
    }
    
    public PageReference next( Map<string,Object> inputMap) {
        system.debug('inputMap--'+inputMap);
        PageReference p = new PageReference('/apex/RentedVP2');
        p.setRedirect(false);
        return p;
        
    }
    
}
```

PAGE 1

```
<apex:page controller="RentedBike">
    <apex:form >
        


        
        <apex:pageblock title="RentedBikeBilling">
            
            <apex:pageblocksection columns="1" title="RentedBikeBilling" collapsible="false" >
                
                
                
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >customer name</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!custRide.customer__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                
                
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Starting KM</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!custRide.Starting_KM__c}" />
                </apex:pageblocksectionitem>
                
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >Ending KM</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!custRide.Ending_KM__c}" />
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >RideSatrtingDate</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!custRide.Ride_Starting_Date__c}" />
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel >RideEndingDate</apex:outputLabel>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!custRide.Ride_Ending_Date__c}" />
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

                 <apex:commandButton action="{!Savevalue}" value="Save"  /> 
                <!--<apex:commandButton action="{!next}" value="next"/>-->
                
                
                
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

page 2

```
<apex:page Controller="RentedBike">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >

           <apex:repeat value="{!inputMap}" var="inputMapKey">
        <apex:outputText value="{!inputMapKey}" />
        <apex:outputText value="{!inputMap[inputMapKey]}" /><br/>
      </apex:repeat>
          
            

            
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store `inputMap` inside the controller; since both pages share the same controller, the second page will automatically remember the values from the first. Note that you "shadowed" the variable in your `Savevalue` method, which was the primary problem. In addition, your next method, being called from `Savevalue`, didn't return a PageReference to the Visualforce runtime, so no redirect occurred. Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
public with sharing class RentedBike {
    public cust_Ride__c custRide {get;set;}  
    public map<string,Object> inputMap {get;set;}
    public RentedBike() {
        custRide = new cust_Ride__c();
        inputMap = new map<string,Object>();
    }
    public PageReference Savevalue() {
        inputMap.put('customer__c',custRide.customer__c);
        inputMap.put('Starting_KM__c',custRide.Starting_KM__c);
        inputMap.put('Ending_KM__c',custRide.Ending_KM__c);
        inputMap.put('Ride_Starting_Date__c',custRide.Ride_Starting_Date__c);
        inputMap.put('Ride_Ending_Date__c',custRide.Ride_Ending_Date__c);
        inputMap.put('Active_Price__c',80);
        inputMap.put('Previous_Price__c',75);
        inputMap.put('Current_Price__c',84);
        PageReference p = new Page.RentedVP2;
        p.setRedirect(false);
        return p;
    }
    
}
```